# Docker pull package using github actions - unauthorized

Tags: docker, github

I tried the following to pull a private package from Github packages using Github workflow. The following is being deployed to a Digital Ocean Droplet.

```
  - name: Build and deploy images on DigitalOcean
    env:
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
    run: |
      scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./prod.yml root@${{ secrets.DIGITAL_OCEAN_IP_ADDRESS_1 }}:/app
      ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${{ secrets.DIGITAL_OCEAN_IP_ADDRESS_1 }} << 'ENDSSH'
        source .env
        docker login ghcr.io -u $NAMESPACE -p $PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
        docker pull $SOME_IMAGE
        docker-compose -f up -d
      ENDSSH
```

I get the following:

> Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device Error
> response from daemon: Head
> https://ghcr.io/v2/orgName/repoName/packageName/manifests/eb69255cb36d62e92719a0531a716c2438945a50:
> unauthorized Pulling packageName
> (ghcr.io/orgName/repoName/packageName:eb69255cb36d62e92719a0531a716c2438945a50)...
> Head
> https://ghcr.io/v2/kontur-as/compute/backend/manifests/eb69255cb36d62e92719a0531a716c2438945a50:
> unauthorized

Can someone please help on how to pull the private container and bypass the unauthorized error?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do the following on digital ocean first.

```
echo PERSONAL_TOKEN_HERE | docker login ghcr.io -u ORGNAME --password-stdin
```

I guess this adds the required authentication on the digital ocean server.